# Where is "navigate to" in Visual Studio 2010 Express C#

Tags: visual-studio-express, missing-features

Is "Navigate to" one of the "missing" features from Visual Studio Express 2010?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

that is indeed missing in the express edition.

Comment: seems like there are some hints to that effect here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4sadchd3.aspx

Comment: @Igor yes I saw that page already but I cannot see what is available for what VS edition.

Comment: Yeah, looks like an undocumented omission.

Comment: Can someone confirm or deny that it is available in 2012 express? That alone would make me upgrade to 2012 (EXPRESS). Thanks!

Comment: @keyle, 2012 express is no good either. Would reccommend a plugin i think.

Comment: @keyle, see my solution if you're still struggling a year later :D

Answer (score 0):

Neither *navigate to* or *extensions* are included in the express versions of visual studio.

However, I use an external file-search program and it works just as well (Maybe quicker?)

[Launchy](http://www.launchy.net/) - which brings a text input to focus in Windows on a keystroke (with a few modified settings):

- I've changed the keystroke to `CTRL + ,`
- Set the *Catalog* to my current source directory
- Set only my source file-types be searched
- Set the Include executables/directories to false
- Auto open delay to 10ms
- Check *Hide Launchy when it loses focus*
- And Rescan the catalog

Then I just make sure all my source files are set to open with visual studio and as long as they're in my solution, it'll open the file as if I navigated to it in the Solution Explorer.

**Bonuses**: Launchy uses a more fuzzy search than Navigate To, and doesn't bloat VS's already poor performance.